# Laravel: Add custom validation class make fail attributes() method in Request class

Tags: validation, laravel, attributes

I have code in Request class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required|check_xxx',
    ];
}

public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'AAA',
    ];
}
```

As you can see. I have cusom validation method name **check_xxx**. This method in inside class **CustomValidator**.

So, I have code:

```
class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
}
```

And error message for **required** is: **Please input :attribute**

But I got the message: **Please input id**, (TRUE is: Please input AAA)

I discovered that **$this->app->validator->resolver** make **attributes()** method in Request is useless.

How can I fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in `Laravel 5.2` but found a QUICK solution as following. In example following you will add rule directly inside the APP Provider.

**File to add rule: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        // ....

        #/
        #/ Adding rule "even_number" to check even numbers.
        #/ 
        \Validator::extend('even_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
              $value = intval($value);
              return ($value % 2) == 0);

        // ...

    }
```